# Differentiate complex function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$f(z)=3z^2+\bar{z}$$

I want to show the function is either differentiable or not so I can state if it is holomorphic or not. What is the method for this ?

Edit - Can some give an example of how to apply cauchy riemann equation to this question ?

Comment: One way is to check if it satisfies Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: What do you get when you differentiate z with a bar on top

Comment: It is not unlikely that you will find an elementary proof that $\bar z$ is not differentiable (in the complex sense) in your lecture notes or text.

Comment: in some cases z=x+iy but we are not told if that is the case. So the answer must be that I cannot diffrentiate it, I cannot say it is continuous or a holomorphic

Comment: If $z = x+iy$ then $\overline{z} = x-iy = x + i(-y)$. Differentiate the real and imaginary parts in $x$ and $y$. Do they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(z)$ were differentiable, then $f(z)-3z^2=\bar{z}$ would be differentiable since $3z^2$ is. However, $\bar{z}$ is not complex differentiable. Check this with the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).

Comment: so if the differential with respect to x is equal to the differential with respect to y. the Cauchy riemann conditions are satisfied and the function is differentiable ?

y' = 0
z'= 6z ?

Comment: @Amy2014: No. A function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is complex differentiable if and only if $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued. Another way to look at this would be $$i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Answer (score -1):

This function is differentiable everywhere except at z=0.  As with real differentiation, complex differentiation is still a linear operation, meaning that d/dz( $3z^2 + \bar{z}$) = d/dz ($3z^2$) + d/dz ($\bar{z}$).  The first term is differentiable everywhere.  The second term is not differentiable at zero because $\bar{z}'(0) = \lim_{z->0} (\bar{z}-0)/(z-0)$, and $\bar{z}/z$ can take on different values as $z->0$ for different directions (e.g. if you approach z from the positive real axis, $\bar{z}/z -> 1$; if you approach from the positive imaginary axis, $\bar{z}/z->-1$.  Here is a good page detailing this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function

Comment: $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is nowhere complex differentiable.